# Public case overview via checksum

Tags: civicase

Does anybody have a clue how to provide a personalized (id & checksum) case overview for clients in civicrm and drupal. I'm stuck with webforms, formprocessor, contact overview and profiles (all no activities and relationships list) and with drupal views (not personalizable by query params).
What am I missing?

(I tried to use Data processor as well, but it's not working atm. Would this be the solution?)

Comment: Do you mean an overview of a single case, or of all cases (like the dashboard)?

Comment: I'm okay with a one-case-view and with an all-my-cases-view. I just need a personalized access to case information or at least an activities list using checksum url instead of login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by utilizing Webforms, CiviCoop's Dataprocessor and/or FormProcessor.